# Align an image to fit in area of a cover background image?

Tags: html, css

I have this background image:
https://i.ibb.co/b5v8P1B/backgroundimage.jpg

... and this box image:
https://i.ibb.co/Kx6gtNJ/box.jpg

I want the background image to be a cover image and no matter how I resize the browser, I need to figure out (calculate) the cordinates of the grey box, so I can place the red box excatcly over the grey box like this final image:

[image]

Here's some test code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/b5v8P1B/backgroundimage.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/Kx6gtNJ/box.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution will work for you in each and every case. If you find something wrong ping me in comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
            padding:0;
        }

        .container {
            
            padding:0;
            margin:auto;
        }

        .background {
            background: url("https://i.ibb.co/b5v8P1B/backgroundimage.jpg") no-repeat center top;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top:75%;
            position:relative;
        }

        .box {
            background: url("https://i.ibb.co/Kx6gtNJ/box.jpg") no-repeat center center;
            position:absolute;
            width:15%;
            height:13.33%;
            z-index:1000;
            left:42.5%;
            top: calc(15% - 1px);
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="background">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have an issue tracking the horizontal movement but the vertical movement is tricky. The gray box moves vertically just a little bit and this solution doesn't account for that.

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/b5v8P1B/backgroundimage.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/Kx6gtNJ/box.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

}
```